# How do I uninstall ethereum-unstable from ubantu 17.10?

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu

I want to install the stable version of ethereum.

I have performed the below steps to download the unstable version of it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum-unstable
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install ethereum` ? The default version will be the stable one.

You might need to uninstall the unstable one first:

`sudo apt-get uninstall ethereum-unstable`

The [Ethereum documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu#installing-from-ppa) also covers the installation step.s